# SQL Server 2012 - Adding a summary row

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have this code

```
SELECT 
    B.TABLENAME AS [TABLE NAME], 
    B.SIZE AS [SIZE PRE-CLEANUP GIG(S)], 
    A.SIZE AS [SIZE POST-CLEANUP GIG(S)], 
    B.SIZE - A.SIZE AS [SIZE CHANGE GIG(S)],
    CASE
       WHEN B.SIZE = 0 OR A.SIZE = 0
           THEN '0.0%'
           ELSE FORMAT((B.SIZE-A.SIZE)/B.SIZE, 'P1')
    END AS [PERCENTAGE OF CHANGE]
FROM 
    ZERO_BALANCE.DBO.TMP_TABLE_STATS_BEG AS B
JOIN
    ZERO_BALANCE.DBO.TMP_TABLE_STATS_END AS A ON A.TABLENAME = B.TABLENAME
```

which display a table that looks like the attached image. How would I make a summary row for this?

[image]

Comment: Add another query matching the one above with your summations and do a union all between the 2

Comment: Sometimes it the easy things that cause me the most confusion.  Thank you for your reply.